# What's causing my Macbook air not see WiFi unless I turn on & connect via mobile hotspot first?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, mac, router, macbook

I have this weird problem with my MacBook Air. And this happens quite often. My macbook doesn't show my home WiFi on the available WiFi list. It searches for wireless networks and I can see other wifis from my neighborhood.

I had accidentally discovered this as I didn't have internet so I would always connect my phone as a hotspot to use the internet. Magically when I connect to the hotspot/phone then the WiFi starts to show in the wireless network list on mac and only now I can connect and it works fine.
So I have to connect to my hotspot/phone everytime I open the laptop in order to connect to my WiFi. What is the root-cause of this and please suggest how can I fix the problem.
WiFi shows up sometimes on my laptop but not always. WiFi network shows up fine on other devices such as mobile phones and laptops, so it must be this Macbook.

Comment: Create a new user. Login as new user. Does your wifi appear now?

Comment: @JohnnyVegas Let me try that and I will get back to you :)

Comment: @JohnnyVegas I logging in as a new user but the issue remains same. The confusing part is why Wifi only shows up after I turn on and connect my hotspot?

Comment: Remove the adapter in system prefs by using the - symbol. Apply, restart then add the adapter again using the + symbol